# Wordpress on Azure - How to change file upload limits

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to edit the WordPress upload limits for my site to at least 2GB for a migration

I'm using WordPress on Azure (Linux), which uses this container under the hood: appsvc/wordpress-alpine-php:latest

I've tried the methods online such as editing the .htaccess file, please see a snippet from the top of mine below

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 4096M
php_value post_max_size 4096M
php_value memory_limit 4096M
php_value max_execution_time 3000
php_value max_input_time 3000
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType application/javascript .js2
 ... etc etc
```

Unfortunately this method hasn't worked - has anyone come across this or have any suggestions?

Many thanks